# Web Application Interactions with Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Bear with me :)

I have a website (ASP.NET MVC4) in which I intend to allow users to share the occasional photo on Facebook.  The photos are not publicly visible, so a link won't suffice.  Instead, I'd like to upload the photo to the user's Facebook account.  It's my understanding that my Facebook app can support this, and that it would create an app-specific album in the user's profile.  Which is ideal.

Now, my Facebook development experience (and OAuth experience in general) is minimal at best.  But from what I can piece together, the flow would go something like this:

- Present the user with a link to a Facebook resource which contains:

  - My Facebook App ID
  - The permission(s) I'm requesting
  - A callback to my website
- Facebook would prompt the user to accept the permission(s) and redirect to the callback (or immediately redirect if they've already otherwise granted permissions)
- The redirect back to a resource on my site would include in the query string a time-sensitive token that I'd use in my server-side code (C# SDK in this case) to upload to the user's profile, as well as perhaps the user's Facebook ID to be used in the graph API request.

This is just conceptual at this point, while I've been looking around for a little while for some concrete examples.  Any example I find tends to involve slightly different flows to accomplish slightly different things and is *just outside* what I'm trying to accomplish.  So that's why I say I've been "piecing this together."

Is this conceptual flow accurate?  Is this how I should be proceeding?  If so, then the meat of the question is:

- What is the format of the Facebook resource to which I'd be directing the user?
- What is the format of the callback parameters I'd get back?

Or... am I completely going in the wrong direction here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have pieced it together correctly. But for the third point, it's a little bit different. Facebook will do redirect back to a resource on your site but it would include a simple access code in the query string and not a access token.
`http://yoursite.com/FacebookShare.aspx?code=access_code`

You've to exchange this code with a user access token, so that you can make calls to the graph API on behalf of the user.

For how to exchange and your later two question read this [tutorial](http://www.thepcwizard.in/2013/02/working-with-facebook-c--sharp-sdk.html).
Comment if you face any problem. A MVC specific tutorial is [here](http://blog.ntotten.com/2012/12/19/facebook-authentication-with-the-facebook-c-sdk-and-asp-net-mvc-4/).